# CSS media and query not working?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

This is my CSS media query code in `header.html` file. i write css media query in html file.

```
<style type="text/css">

@media (min-width:100px ) and (max-width:480px ){
    .background-color-sec-1-images {
        background-image: url("localhost/set/img/img1.jpg");
        background-repeat:no-repeat; 
        background-size:100% 100%;
    }        
}
@media (min-width:480px ) and (max-width:768px ){
    .background-color-sec-1-images {
        background-image: url("localhost/set/img/img1.jpg");
        background-repeat:no-repeat; 
        background-size:100% 100%;
    }        
}
@media (min-width:768px ) and (max-width:1200px ){
    .background-color-sec-1-images {
        background-image: url("localhost/set/img/img1.jpg");
        background-repeat:no-repeat; 
        background-size:100% 100%;
    }        
}      
</style>
```

This CSS is not working.

When i write css like this is working fine.

```
    <style type="text/css">

@media (min-width:100px ){
    .background-color-sec-1-images {
        background-image: url("localhost/set/img/img1.jpg");
        background-repeat:no-repeat; 
        background-size:100% 100%;
    }        
}
@media (min-width:480px ){
    .background-color-sec-1-images {
        background-image: url("localhost/set/img/img1.jpg");
        background-repeat:no-repeat; 
        background-size:100% 100%;
    }        
}
@media (min-width:768px ){
    .background-color-sec-1-images {
        background-image: url("localhost/set/img/img1.jpg");
        background-repeat:no-repeat; 
        background-size:100% 100%;
    }        
}      
</style>
```

But This is overwrite css. so this is not working for me.

but why not working @media (min-width:100px) and (max-width:400px) query?

thank you.

Comment: try `min-width:481px ` and try `min-width:769px ` in the second and third.

Comment: i try not but working thank's.

Comment: Have you tried adding `http://` to your paths?

Comment: The CSS seems fine http://jsfiddle.net/8V3L7/, background images are swapping out for me. Are you certain it's the media queries that are causing the problem? Can you provide more context for this?

Comment: @Serlite i mention that the i write css in html page so that not working?

Comment: Hm, an inline stylesheet seems to work fine too. (http://jsfiddle.net/8V3L7/1/) Are you sure your paths to your images are correct, and there aren't any overriding styles after these?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/GV4v3/ it works fine

Comment: yes image path is correct. but image path is not change wise resolution.

Comment: Uuuh. Do you have a live example of the page? Or can you set it up at http://jsfiddle.net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edited:
in pure css, you have to declare your media and INSIDE put your conditions.

```
@media print { // rule (1)
  #anId{ 
    //something here
   }
  @media (max-width: 12cm) { // rule (2)
    //something here
  }
}
```

[here docs](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-conditional/)

so first of your rules can be:

```
@media screen{
  @media (min-width:100px ) and (max-width:480px ){
    .background-color-sec-1-images {
        background-image: url("localhost/set/img/img1.jpg");
        background-repeat:no-repeat; 
        background-size:100% 100%;
    }        
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you must declare which media you are using:

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_mediatypes.asp

so in your case use as follows:

```
@media screen (min-width:100px ) {
/* your styling goes here */
}
```